# Json data reading

Tags: json, c#-4.0

I have following json format data reading problem

I tried this code which is not working because Answer node have Answer named data

```
   string filePath = Server.MapPath("../App_Data/history.txt");
          using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            List<RootObject> Questions = 
             JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
    public class Answer
    {
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    }

    public class Question
    {
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public int CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    }
```

JSON Data :

```
 {
 "Questions": [


  {
      "Question": "Who was the Chola King who brought Ganga from North to South?",
      "CorrectAnswer": 1   ,
      "Answers": [
       {
      "Answer": "Raja Raja Chola"
       },
       {
      "Answer": "Rajendra Chola"
    },
    {
      "Answer": "Parantaka"
    },
    {
      "Answer": "Mahendra"
    }
  ]
}, 


{

   "Question": "The writ of 'Habeas Corpus' is issued in the event of:",
   "CorrectAnswer":  2  ,
   "Answers": [
    {
      "Answer": "Loss of Property"
    },
    {
      "Answer": "Refund of Excess Taxes"
    },
      {
      "Answer": "Wrongful Police Detention"
     },
      {
      "Answer": "Violation of the Freedom of Speech"
     }
     ]
   }
   ]}
```